# Assign values to different index positions as the actual in a loop python

Tags: python, numpy, loops, indexing, position

I have the next variables which are List, floats and a numpy array.

```py
dt=list(range(1,12))   
c=18
limit=2.75
Energy=np.zeros(len(dt))
```

I want to assign the value `c=18` in the Numpy array `Energy`. However, there is a condition. The value in the `Energy` vector can not be greater than `limit=2.75`, so as `c=18` is greater than `limit=2.75`, it should be cut to `2.5` and assigned in the actual index position of the loop and in the next index positions of the vector `Energy` until the value `18` is reached. I made this code but it does not really work efficiently.

```py
for i in range(0,1): 
    if c>limit:
        tmp2=c-(limit)
        if tmp2>(limit):
            tmp3=tmp2-(limit)
            if tmp3>limit:
                tmp4=tmp3-(limit)
                if tmp4>(limit):
                    tmp5=tmp4-(limit)
                    if tmp5>(limit):
                        tmp6=tmp5-(limit)
                        if tmp6>limit:
                            tmp7=tmp6-(limit)
                            if tmp7>(limit):
                                tmp8=tmp7-(limit)
                            else:
                                Energy[i]=limit
                                Energy[i+1]=limit
                                Energy[i+2]=limit
                                Energy[i+3]=limit
                                Energy[i+4]=limit
                                Energy[i+5]=limit
                                Energy[i+6]=tmp7
```

Do you have an idea of how to make it better? Thank you!

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Why is there so little whitespace in your code?

Comment: I am learning, thanks for the suggestions. I think also it is more understandable with more withspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

Your code presently uses a loop where it doesn't need one and doesn't use a loop where it could be used.

Stepping into your code:

```
for i in range(0,1):
```

If we change this to:

```
for i in range(0,1): 
    print (i)
```

We will get the result 0 - it only runs once so there is no need to loop it - i isn't referred to in your code so there is no need to loop through it.

You could use a loop to allocate your c to an array but it isn't needed and I'll leave that as an exercise for yourself.

It can be approached in a different, more efficient way.

First of all when you're assigning variables try and make them descriptive and readable - you'll spend a lot more time coming back to code than you do reading it.

I don't know what system you're describing so I've just given generic names:

import numpy as np

```
length_arrary=12

limit=2.75

value_to_be_assigned=18

energy_result=np.zeros(length_arrary)
```

Now what we are really asking is two things, how many times does value_to_be_assigned divide into the limit (an integer) and what is the remainder.

Python has two operations for this floor division (//) and modulus which give:

```
11//5 = 2.0
1%5   = 1.0
```

So we know the first (value_to_be_assigned//limit elements - 1) of the array need to be equal to the limit and the final element needs to be equal to value_to_be_assigned % limit

Finally Python has an easy way to access elements of a list - we can set the first x elements to be equal to a value with:

```
array[:x]=value
```

x just needs to be an integer.

Putting it together we get:

```
filled_values=int(value_to_be_assigned//limit)

energy_result[:filled_values]=limit

energy_result[filled_values] = value_to_be_assigned % limit
```

and we can check with

```
energy_result.sum() # gives us 18
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, comments and suggestions! I really appreciate it! All the best.